# Can't dynamically create path with upload_to

Tags: django, django-models

In my user model, I have an `ImageField` that contains an `upload_to` attribute that will create the image path dynamically based on the user's id.

```
avatar  = models.ImageField(storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=create_user_image_path)

def create_user_image_path(instance, image_name):
    image_name = str(instance.user.id) + image_name[-4:]
    return 'users/{0}/avatars/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, image_name)
```

When I sign up, I get an error that looks like this:

> The system cannot find the path specified:
>   'C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\project_name\media\users\150\avatars'

If I remove the id and avatars and just include the image name (with no new directories) it works successfully and writes the image. I have tried doing `chmod -R 777` on this directory, but it still doesn't create these new directories dynamically. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

```
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, *args, **kwargs):

        # Delete all avatars in directory before adding new avatar.
        # (Sometimes we have different extension names, so we can't delete by name
        file_path = os.path.dirname(name)
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_path))

        return name
```

The problem I see is because of my `OverwriteStorage` function. When I remove it, it saves. How can I fix this function so that it overwrites if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem id with `instance.user.id`
I would suggest you try to import the User as below it may help

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

def create_user_image_path(instance, image_name):
    image_name = str(user) + image_name[-4:]
    return 'users/{0}/avatars/{1}'.format(user.id, image_name)
```

However django recommends to user `AUTH_USER_MODEL`
implementation

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

## Update

When you look into override storage, the variable `name` gets the name of the image you are about to upload. Your `file_path = os.path.dirname(name)`, you are returning a folder with image name. When shutil.rmtree ties to find the folder, it returns error it cannot find the path. Use conditional statement i.e. `if` or `try except block` as shown below.

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
import os


class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        """Returns a filename that's free on the target storage system, and
        available for new content to be written to.

        Found at http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/976/

        This file storage solves overwrite on upload problem. Another
        proposed solution was to override the save method on the model
        like so (from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11663):

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                this = MyModelName.objects.get(id=self.id)
                if this.MyImageFieldName != self.MyImageFieldName:
                    this.MyImageFieldName.delete()
            except: pass
            super(MyModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        """
        # If the filename already exists, remove it as if it was a true file system
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
            # default_storage.delete(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
        return name
```

Like in your case

```
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, *args, **kwargs):

        # Delete all avatars in directory before adding new avatar.
        # (Sometimes we have different extension names, so we can't delete by name
        if self.exists(name):
            file_path = os.path.dirname(name)
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_path))

        return name
```

Comment: The user id works correctly and it's using the Django User implementation, however, the problem is with my override storage which I still dont know why